# GroupPrincipal Rename group

Tags: c#, linq, rename, principalcontext, groupprincipal

I'm trying to rename a group. My code looks like the following

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "GroupName");
group.SamAccountName = "NewGroupName";
group.DisplayName = "NewGroupName";
group.Name = "NewGroupName";
group.Save();
```

The problem is that it crashes at `group.DisplayName = "NewGroupName";` and throws the exception

> property is not valid for this store type.

If I comment out that line the code will run on but I would like to change the Display name. I did some research and found [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086806/inexplainable-invalidoperationexception-with-groupprincipal-and-sam-principalcon) However I am using Framework 4.0. Does anyone know another what to do this or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much deliberation I has found the only way to get `group.Name = "Newname";` to work is to get the DirectoryEntry object and then change it. Code below

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "GroupName");
var Groupentry = (DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
Groupentry.Rename("newname");
Groupentry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Solution works, although I got an error `DirectoryServicesCOMException: An invalid dn syntax has been specified`. Fixed with: `Groupentry.Rename($"cn={newName}");`